# Behringer UM2 weird white/static noise problem

Tags: audio, noise, audio-interfaces, behringer

I have recently stumbled up upon a weird problem with my audio interface. I'm using a Behringer U-PHORIA UM2, with an Audio-Technica AT2020 mic connected to it. When I first got it there was no problem, but one time that I tried recording there was this white/static noise, and I thought that it had to be a problem with the microphone, but when bringing the mic gain down, the microphone gets quieter but the noise doesn't and it's still there as loud as it was. I thought this must be a problem with the interface or the cable then, but I connected the same interface with the same microphone with the same cables to another PC, and it worked flawlessly. I tried switching up the USB ports from 2.0 to 3.0 and backwards, turning on and off the 48V power thing and nothing helped. I don't know what to do now so if anybody knows how to help me I would be really grateful.